# Issue when trying to connect to team foundation server

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am quite new to Visual Studio and are trying to connect to a team foundation server. First I want to point out that if I go to the URL of the TFS in my browser and enter my credentials there I get access to the code etc, so there is no problem with the credentials itself.

Basically what I have done in Visual Studio 2012 is go to:
Team Explorer -> Connect to Team Foundation Server -> Servers -> Add -> Enter my credentials.

So after that a login screen appears which prompts for username/password ( which is very logic ), however here when I enter the same credentials I don't get access. In that login screen I can also see a "Domain" which seem to be something random that I have just entered when I installed windows and that domain has nothing to do with the TFS.

As you probably noticed I don't really know what that domain thingy does? Can that be the problem why I can't connect to the TFS server through Visual Studio but it works through the browser? Also if that matters I am connected via VPN to the place where the TFS server is located.

Comment: The domain is part of your credentials.  What credentials - exactly - are you entering in your browser?

Comment: I am just entering the url in the browser, like http://myServer:8080/tfs/. Then I get asked for username/password and after I entered those I get access. Can it be because I am logged in with vpn that I get some other domain in the browser case?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem connecting to TFS over VPN. I've been connecting with no problems for months, but I changed my Windows password while in the office yesterday, and couldn't log on from my laptop today.

Turns out that in the credentials box I was omitting my domain name. So instead of MY-WORK-DOMAIN\Itar I was just entering Itar.

(There was a domain name underneath - uneditable - that referred to my wireless router. That doesn't seem to be relevant when signing in.)

Once I entered my username as MY-WORK-DOMAIN\Itar and entered the new password it all worked.

I'm sure the OP has been sorted out by now, but maybe my answer will be useful to someone else.